# Node.js and serialport 2 way communication

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-serialport

I'm trying to create a service to send SMS via GSM modem connected to my server.

I wrote a C# application which does that and right now I want to re-write it to use Node.js and node-serialport (https://github.com/voodootikigod/node-serialport) module.

To send SMS i need to have 2 way communication. I mean like that:

```
REQ: AT
RES: /r/nOK/r/n
REQ: SOMETHING
RES: /r/n/OK/r/n
REQ: SOMETHING 2
RES: /r/nMESSAGE SENT/r/n
```

I have problem with writing it under JavaScript, because node-serialport library allows only asynchronous reading and asynchronous writing to a port.

My question is: How should I do this?

My first idea is to write a big 'on data received' function, which will store actual status of my workflow and according to that, handles responses in proper way. But this will result in BIG and UGLY code.

Could you help me with that?

Comment: hey @tomsaz did you achieve this with node.js? I am trying to do same any help will be appreciated.